# Javascript Compare data value in loop with if

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'want to get data with my criteria.

```js
var data_user = [{
    "username": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "username": "bbb"
  }
]

var data_tim = [{
    "nama": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "nama": "bbb"
  },
  {
    "nama": "ccc"
  }
]

$.each(data_tim, function(key_tim, val_tim) {
  $.each(data_user, function(key_usr, val_usr) {
    if (val_tim.nama == val_usr.username) {
//just show aaa,bbb : in this line it's right
      console.log("KIRIM EMAIL PEMBERITAHUAN SURVEY DENGAN INFORMASI SURAT TUGASNYA SAJA TO:" + val_usr.username);
    } else {
//actualy just show ccc, but now display wrong: aaa,bbb,ccc,ccc
      console.log("TAMBAH DATA, KIRIM EMAIL SURVEY DENGAN INFORMASI SURAT TUGAS DAN INFORMASI USER LOGIN TO:" + val_tim.nama);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If u see my var data_user and data_tim. the data user just have 2 data and the data tim is have tree, i want to validate.
if(data user equals data tim) then set message "JUST SEND" 
else if the data not equals just set message "CREATE AND SEND".

My code in up, i think its right, but in line else the give me wrong value, is : `aaa,bbb,ccc,ccc` the right value must be just : `ccc` because we know just value ccc not have equals.

thanks

Comment: Your code seems to bear little resemblance to what you're asking. What does 'set message' *mean* in your case? Please clarify.

Comment: You want to check if each `username` in `data_user` exist in `data_tim`?

Comment: @eddie yes dude, that's i mean :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any library, you can use `new Set()` to get the list of `data_user` `username`. Use `forEach` to loop thru `data_tim` and check each if the `nama` exist on the temp variable.

```js
var data_user = [
  {"username": "aaa"},
  {"username": "bbb"}
]

var data_tim = [
  {"nama": "aaa"},
  {"nama": "bbb"},
  {"nama": "ccc"}
]

var dataTemp = new Set(data_user.map(o => o.username));
data_tim.forEach(o => {

  if (dataTemp.has(o.nama)) {
    console.log(o.nama + " - JUST SEND!");
  } else {
    console.log(o.nama + " - CREATE AND SEND!");
  }

});
```

**Option 2:** Using object instead of `Set`

```js
var data_user = [
  {"username": "aaa"},
  {"username": "bbb"}
]

var data_tim = [
  {"nama": "aaa"},
  {"nama": "bbb"},
  {"nama": "ccc"}
]

var dataTemp = data_user.reduce((c, v) => (c[v.username] = true, c), {});

data_tim.forEach(o => {

  if (o.nama in dataTemp) {
    console.log(o.nama + " - JUST SEND!");
  } else {
    console.log(o.nama + " - CREATE AND SEND!");
  }

});
```

**Option 3:** Using `some` to check if atleast one array element on `data_user` has username == nama

```js
var data_user = [
  {"username": "aaa"},
  {"username": "bbb"}
]

var data_tim = [
  {"nama": "aaa"},
  {"nama": "bbb"},
  {"nama": "ccc"}
]

data_tim.forEach(o => {

  if (data_user.some(s => s.username === o.nama)) {
    console.log(o.nama + " - JUST SEND!");
  } else {
    console.log(o.nama + " - CREATE AND SEND!");
  }

});
```

Comment: thanks verry much, @eddie, u'r method its work.
I will try in my code now :D

but if u still have other way, not use new Set please share :D(y)(y)

Comment: @CarboniBag I added 2 more different sample (without `Set`). Just click on "Show code snippet" :)

Comment: Verry Great, I like Option 3, again thanks verry much
God bless u :D

Comment: Happy to help :)